# Laravel 5 Mail template showing html tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I have the main mail template (resources/views/mail.blade.php). This is a common template to use all of my mail like for forgot password or for change new password. The content for mail.blade.php is below:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>SiteName</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>{{$content}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm storing the content of email template (in mySql db) through CKEditor and it looks like:

```html
<p>Dear {{$username}},</p>
<p>This is your new password: {{$newPassword}}</p>
```

Now I using mail function in laravel 5.5 as below:

```
$content = str_replace(array('username', 'newPassword'), array($userName, $request->confirm_password), addslashes($emailTemplate->templateBody));

Mail::send(['html' => 'mail'], ['content' => $content], function ($message) use($emailTemplate, $user){
$message->from($emailTemplate->fromEmail, $emailTemplate->fromName);
$message->to($user->email);
});
```

After sending email in mailtrap.io, I see the mail looks like:

```html
SiteName
<p>Dear Niladri,</p> <p>This is your new password: 123456</p>
```

Please note, the table, tr, td where SiteName is written in the mail.blade is working and no HTML code is showing in the email. That's fine. But only the content from the CKEditor is showing with HTML tags (`<p></p>`).

Have I did anything wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use HTML content from a PHP variable within a `.blade.php` file, you need to use `{!! $variable !!}` instead of `{{ $variable }}`. The first will render your HTML, the second will output it as a string, including the HTML tags. Your `mail.blade.php` file should look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>SiteName</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{!! $content !!}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `{!! $content !!}`  instead of `{{ $content }}`
It will work perfectly.I had faced the same problem.

Comment: Hey Just Send me the link Of that Wordpress Website.